# What is the need of mapping servlet to URL in Java?

Tags: java, servlets

Can anyone tell me why do we need of mapping servlet to URL in Java? Can't we use servlet name in place of URL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can register same servlet with multiple url mappings on the same website, and indeed register the same servlet class as different servlets in a web application, each with different url mappings - perhaps there is a need for different `<init-param>` configurations.

The name a developer happens to set for the servlet in web.xml may not be appropriate for customers of the website, so is often not the best term to use.

Additionally, url mappings may be multi-levels path such as below, which cannot be handled if you were to rely on the url == servlet name:

```
<url-pattern>/another/name/*</url-pattern>
```